# Generate Purchase From the sale order,

Tags: python, openerp-7

1.so inherit here sale order and m2o field for po but it has given me error i.e `except_orm:Programming Error There is no reference available for purchase.order`

2.I also want to subtract purchase order  subtotal price from the sale order subtotal price and show on to the sale order Total Price

```
class sale_inherit_course(orm.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order'  
   _columns={
            'create_course':fields.boolean('Create Course'),
            'course_name':fields.many2one('openacademy.course', 'Course', ondelete="cascade"),
           'responsible': fields.related('course_name', 'responsible_id', type='many2one', relation='res.users', string="co-ordinator", readonly=True),
           'buy_back':fields.boolean('Buy Back'),
           'purchase_order':fields.many2one('purchase.order', 'Create Back Order', ondelete="cascade"),
           'responsible_me': fields.related('purchase_order', 'responsible_id', type='many2one', relation='res.users', string="User", readonly=True),

          }
    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        if vals.get('create_course'):
            course_obj=self.pool.get('openacademy.course')
            sequence=self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'openacademy.course.seq')
            new_course=course_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name':sequence,'responsible_id':vals.get('user_id')}, context=context)
            import pprint
           pprint.pprint( vals )
           vals['course_name']=new_course
          pprint.pprint( vals )
      elif vals.get('buy_back'):
          purchase_obj=self.pool.get('purchase.order')
          sequence=self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order')
          new_purchase=purchase_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name':sequence,'responsible_id':vals.get('user_id')}, context=context)
          vals['purchase_order']=new_purchase

    return super(sale_inherit_course, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

Here Error Occur that is

```
except_orm: ('Programming Error', 'There is no reference available for purchase.order'
```

Comment: No idea what this code is meant to do, but I find it suspicious that you seem to create a column `'purchase_order'` and then always refer to a column `'purchase.order'`. Might this be the problem?

Comment: yes i want purchase order from the sales Order and calculate the total price like (sale_order_totalprice=(sale_order_subtotal_price - purchase_order_total_price))

Comment: yes your hint solvable for me, but How i can compute the value of purchase and sale

Comment: Would be best if you put this as a new question with the other bug fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_inherit='sale.order'

```
def _amount_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    cur_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
    res = {}

    for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):


        res[order.id] = {
            'amount_untaxed': 0.0,
            'amount_tax': 0.0,
            'amount_total': 0.0,
            'amt_total':0.0
        }
        val = val1 =  0.0
        cur = order.pricelist_id.currency_id
        for line in order.order_line:
            val1 += line.price_subtotal

            val += self._amount_line_tax(cr, uid, line, context=context)
        res[order.id]['amount_tax'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val)
        res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val1)
        #import pprint
        #pprint.pprint( res[order.id]['amt_total'] )
        res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] -= order.amt_total
        res[order.id]['amount_total'] = res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] + res[order.id]['amount_tax']
   #     res[order.id]['amount_total'] -=order.amt_total
    return res


def _get_order(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    result = {}
    for line in self.pool.get('sale.order.line').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result[line.order_id.id] = True
    return result.keys()
```

Field

```
 'purchase_order':fields.many2one('purchase.order', 'Old Gold', ondelete="cascade"),
            'amt_total':fields.related('purchase_order', 'amount_total', type='float', relation='purchase.order', string="Amount", readonly=True),
            'qty_related':fields.related('purchase_order','order_line', 'product_qty', type='float',relation='purchase.order', string='Weight',readonly=True),
```